# how to inject the javascript code into iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have an iframe(src is google.com)..I want to inject the javascript code for find the list of anchor tags present in the iframe from parent to iframe.Is it possible to inject the code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible because of the same-origin policy.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy.

And because you do not have access the Google's server configuration, you won't find any help here either: 
[Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)
.

Comment: Thanks kay.I want to find the url navigations occurring in the iframe. How to achieve this.Can you help me?

Comment: @Shankar, you should open another question, so that other user's may participate, too.